# Why the sum of two probabilities is greater than $1$?

Tags: probability

Problem: I have a box that contains balls: 2 black and 5 white. I have the right to take 2 balls in a row without returning. Find the probability that two chosen balls are white:
Since these events are independent:

$$P(A) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) =  \frac{5}{7} + \frac{4}{6} = \frac{29}{21}>1$$ -> why?

Comment: Whenever you get a strange result you should re-evaluate your assumptions.

Comment: You need to multiply, not add.

Comment: $P(A_1 \cap A_2)=P(A_2|A_1)P(A_1)$

Comment: Nuclear Wang but we multiply when the events occur at the same time. These events don't occur at the same time so why we should multiply

Comment: independent events multiply themselves, not add.

Comment: when do we add then?

Comment: Probabilities add for disjoint events, multiply for independent events.

Comment: I suspect someone has been explaining probability to you rather casually.  As Luis Felipe says, you add probabilities when you're talking about the probability of any of a number of disjoint events.  For example, the probability that a family has no more than two children is equal to the probability that they have no children, *plus* the probability that they have one child, *plus* the probability they have two children.

Comment: We multiply when we want the probability of *all* of a number of *independent* events.  For instance, the probability that it rains today *and* my coin flip comes up heads is equal to the probability that it rains today, *times* the probability that my coin flips heads.

Comment: In this case, the multiplication is of a different sort (at least intuitively), specified by Matthew Holder in their comment: The probability that two things happen—independent or not—can be expressed as the probability the first thing happens, *times* the *conditional* probability that the second thing happens *given* that the first thing happens.  So, for example, suppose I hit a baseball with probability $1/4$.  Given that I hit it, the probability that it is caught "on the fly" is $1/3$.  Then the probability that I hit a ball that is caught on the fly is $1/4 \times 1/3 = 1/12$.

Comment: You can think of it like this: Out of any $12$ times, I'll hit the baseball $3$ times (on average), and of those $3$ times, it is caught on the fly $1$ time (on average).

Answer (score 0):

For your example to verify the correct answer consider listing all of the possible and equally likely arrangements of the 2 black and 5 white balls:

[image]

One can count that out of the 21 possible arrangements, 10 of those have the first two balls chosen being white.

That should convince you that adding the two probabilities is not appropriate.

Comment: thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

The two events are dependent events. You need the first one (getting first ball to be white) "and" the second event to happen  ( getting the second ball to be white) at the same time .
So it is "and" relation between two events to happen (be True) at the same time. ( "And"  relation i.e. both events to be true not "Or"  relation i.e. either one of the two events is only true )
So you have to multiply the two events' probabilities not adding